# Retrieve a file before anything else happens

Tags: vuejs2

Iʼm creating a simple SPA that will retrieve data from an API. The page itself is served by a separate backend process which is the only entity that knows the API address. As such, it also provides an endpoint that, among other things, returns the API URL:

```
{
"api_url_base": "http://api.example.org/v1"
}
```

This is needed because the whole thing is deployed at multiple sites where we donʼt have control over DNS records and it may or may not be easy to derive the API URL from the front end appʼs.

Now i need to write my Vue app so nothing can happen until i fetch and process this file. To achieve that, i added to the appʼs `beforeMount` method:

```
this.settings = axios.get('/settings.json');
```

and in my componentsʼ `beforeMount`:

```
var comp = this;
app.__vue__.settings.then((response) => {comp.url = response.data.api_url;});
```

However,it seems the componentʼs `beforeMounted` often runs before the appʼs, and `app. __vue__.settings` is `undefined` when i get to the componentʼs `beforeMount`.

Where do i go wrong? Am I putting things at wrong places, or is my approach completely wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to do it as early as `beforeCreate`? Take a look at the [vue lifecycle](https://vuejs.org/images/lifecycle.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch data before mount the vue app.

```
axios.get('/settings.json').then(response => {
  // do something with response

  new Vue({
    router,
    store,
    render: h => h(App)
  }).$mount('#app')
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way (as suggested in the previous answer) is to make one more call, before anything else. However it brings numerous downsides.

Let me just say that it freezes the loading of your application until the response is received.

There is hope as you can cleverly use (f.e.) good ol' dependency injection to pass the required data to your app.

This article answers this question fully and completely: https://codeburst.io/passing-configuration-to-vue-js-1b96fa8f959

Comment: Your first concern is irrelevant, as that’s exactly what i want: don’t do anything until that file is received. If the file can’t be fetched, the app can show an error message.